Given name / surname while booking a flight
I am trying to book a flight from Mumbai to Bali on 28th July.
My Indian passport has a given name but no surname. Given name is Gursimrat Singh, and there is no surname.
How should I book tickets, as it is mandatory to put both given name and surname on the website?
I will wait for your response before booking the flight tickets!

Does this answer your question? Surname blank on passport - Query about booking airline tickets

The safest way of solving this is to contact the Airline. If you have time, do it via email or another channel where you can keep a record and show to gate/immigration agents in case of further questions.
The easy way, that is likely to work, but not 100 % guaranteed, is to book a flight as:
Given Name: Gursimrat / Surname: Singh.
